# How to use array to make a string replace function without using the str_replace function?

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

For example

```
$string = "Hello world.";
```

"lo" will get replaced with "aa" and "ld" will get replaced with "bb".
Output will be

```
$string = "Helaa worbb";
```

Comment: What you have tried till yet?

Comment: Use [**strtr**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) - with **replace_pairs**. Like so: [https://3v4l.org/7qFZg](https://3v4l.org/7qFZg).

Comment: Converting it to an array and searching for the required string to be replaced. But not sure how to replace 2 characters from that. Thank you. @SahilGulati

Comment: @PritiranjanMishra Try this one.. https://eval.in/800054

Comment: I want to know how to do it without using any predefined string replace function such as str_replace and only using array functions @SahilGulati sir

Comment: instead of using `str_replace` you want to do with some predefined array functions ?

Comment: Only using array functionalities. Does not matter if it is predefined or not. But it should not use any predefined string replace function.

Comment: Whenever I see such requirements I think school assignment xD (or job interview)

Comment: Please let me know the ans @FirstOne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work -

```
$string = "Hello world.";
// pairs to replace
$replace_pairs = array("lo" => 'aa', 'ld' => 'bb');
// loop through pairs
foreach($replace_pairs as $replace => $new)
{
    // if present
    if(strpos($string, $replace)) {
        // explode the string with the key to replace and implode with new key
        $string = implode($new, explode($replace, $string));
    }
}

echo $string;
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/800137)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up, you can optimize this code.

```
// assuming only 2 characters find and replace
$string = "Hello world.";
$aa = str_split($string); //converts string into array
$rp1 = 'aa'; //replace string 1
$rp2 = 'bb'; //replace string 2
$f1 = 'lo'; //find string 1
$f2 = 'ld'; // find string 2
function replaceChar($k1, $k2, $findStr, $replaceStr, $arr){
    $str = $arr[$k1].$arr[$k2];
    if($str == $findStr){
        $ra = str_split($replaceStr);
        $arr[$k1] = $ra[0];
        $arr[$k2] = $ra[1];
    }
    return $arr;
}
for($i=0; $i < count($aa)-1; $i++){
    $k1 = $i;
    $k2 = $i+1;
    $aa = replaceChar($k1, $k2, $f1, $rp1, $aa); //for replace first match string
    $aa = replaceChar($k1, $k2, $f2, $rp2, $aa); // for replace second match string 
}

echo implode('', $aa);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/TsFlc)

Comment: Why not simply use a `array`s, a loop and `str_replace`?

Comment: I have. But there simpler ways to do that I guess.